# How do I dynamically create CartoCSS for a choropleth with CartoDB

Tags: cartodb

I am trying to create choropleth map with CartoDB using the JS library.

How can I dynamically create the cartoCSS on a layer?

It seems possible based on column?

For example using the built in wizard the following was generated. I want to somehow dynamically generate this using custom colors and column names on the frontend.

```css
#mytable{
  polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
  polygon-opacity: 0.8;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-opacity: 1;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 12505.969707] {
   polygon-fill: #B10026;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 3650.909837] {
   polygon-fill: #E31A1C;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 1656.60976] {
   polygon-fill: #FC4E2A;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 677.226857] {
   polygon-fill: #FD8D3C;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 333.140676] {
   polygon-fill: #FEB24C;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 170.576913] {
   polygon-fill: #FED976;
}
#mytable [ col_xyz <= 51.090065] {
   polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
}
```

http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayersetcartocsscss

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'll want to use the createLayer method, making each of the polygons its own sublayer...

```
 cartodb.createLayer(map, {
   user_name: 'mycartodbuser',
   type: 'cartodb',
   sublayers: [{
   sql: "SELECT * FROM table_name",
   cartocss: '#table_name {polygon-fill: #F0F0F0;}'
   },
   {
   sql: "SELECT * FROM table_name",
   cartocss: '#table_name {polygon-fill: #FFFFFF;}'
   }]
 })
 .addTo(map)
 .done(function(layer) {
   //DO STUFF
 });
```

Maybe there are better ways to do this, but it worked for me.

http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html